# Apache 404 Error getting pages from subfolders

Tags: apache2

Many many questions about this and I cannot find an answer.  Simple website SSL, just set up.  My configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mywebserver.io
        Redirect / https://mywebserver.io
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerAdmin me@mywebserver.io
   ServerName mywebserver.io
   SSLEngine on
   SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
   SSLCertificateFile /var/www/ssl/STAR_mywebserver_io.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/ssl/mywebserver.io.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/ssl/SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   <Directory />
      Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
      AllowOverride all
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog /var/log/alt.error.log
   LogLevel warn
   CustomLog /var/log/alt.access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>

Web folder structure:
/etc/www/html
     |------>subfolder
                |------>index.html
```

No .htaccess files in any of the folders, file permissions set to 0777 and the entire folder is owned by www-data.  Browsing to https://mywebserver/subfolder throws a 404 error.  Can someone take a look, please.

Comment: Should that be `https://mywebserver.io/subfolder`? Your post is missing the `.io`. Also, what do you see in the Apache logs, if anything?